# How to select the objects where the ID of a list (of entities) equals a variable using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've got a many to many relationship between `Tariff` and `Insurance`. Here the classes:

```cs
public class Insurance
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tariff> Tariffs { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Insurance ins = obj as Insurance;
        if (ins != null)
        {
            return ins.ID == ID;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class Tariff
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public decimal MinPrice { get; set; }
    public bool Delete { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Insurance> Insurances { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to select all the `Tariff` objects where the property `Insurances` contains an `Insurance` where the `ID` property equals the given variable. For this I've written this code:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Tariff> GetFilteredPublished(int insuranceID)
{
    return (from t in dbSet
            where t.Insurances.Contains(insuranceID)
            select t).ToList();
}
```

This doesn't work because `insuranceID` is not an `Insurance`. When I use this code:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Tariff> GetFilteredPublished(int inscuranceID, int interventionID)
{
    Insurance ins = new Insurance() { ID = inscuranceID };

    return (from t in dbSet
            where t.Insurances.Contains(ins) && t.Intervention.ID == interventionID
            select t).ToList();
}
```

Gives me this exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of type `Insurance`. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

**Notes by the code:**

- On code below you could read what the `dbSet` is.

  ```cs
  internal Context context;
  internal DbSet<Tariff> dbSet;

  public TariffService() // the `TariffService` class is the place where I call 
                         // `GetFilteredPublished`
  {
      context = new Context();
      dbSet = context.Set<Tariff>();
  }
  ```
- I'm using LINQ and Entity Framework.

How could I do this?

Comment: You are looking for [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.any):  `where t.Insurances.Any(i => i.ID == insuranceID)`.

Comment: I know nothing about entity-framework, but for me it looks like you need sth like `t.Insurances.FindAll(i=>i.ID==insureanceID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a comment of @Federico I've found the answer:

```
return (from t in dbSet
        where t.Insurances.Any(i => i.ID == insuranceID) && t.Intervention.ID == interventionID
        select t).ToList();
```

> **`Any()`:** Determines whether any element of an `IQueryable<T>` sequence exists or satisfies a condition.
>
> <sup>Source: [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.any?view=netframework-4.7.1)</sup>

Comment: **t.Insurances.Select(i => i.ID).ToList().Contains(insuranceID)** should also work